# Unity Container - ResolutionFailedException when removing covariance

Tags: unity-container

I have an a unity registration that works just fine with the out covariance, but once I remove it, I get the error

> "ClassName": "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException",
>   "Message": "Resolution of the dependency failed, type = \"REDACTED.IChatTranscriptBc`1[REDACTED]\", name = \"REDACTED\".\r\nException occurred while: Calling constructor Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.CurrentInterceptionRequest interceptionRequest, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[] policies, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container).\r\nException is: ArgumentException - Interface not found.\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving REDACTED.ChatTranscriptBc,REDACTED (mapped from REDACTED.IChatTranscriptBc`1[REDACTED], REDACTED)\r\n    Resolving Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior,(none)\r\n    Calling constructor Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.CurrentInterceptionRequest interceptionRequest, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[] policies, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container)\r\n"

My interface when it works:

```
public interface IChatTranscriptBc<out TTranscript>
    where TTranscript : Transcript
```

My interface when it breaks

```
public interface IChatTranscriptBc<TTranscript>
    where TTranscript : Transcript
```

Literally, the only change is my removal of "out."  I've rebuilt all my libraries, restarted my computer, everything.  Any idea why the removal of the covariance breaks unity?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was resolving to IChatTranscript and the concrete class it matched to did not match that exact definition (it was using an implementation of Transcript, not Transcript itself).  Bubbling up, it threw that error.